# How to create URL with path parameters inside API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I want to create a path as follows in the API Gateway:-
    `/users/{userId}/photos/{photoId}.`
A clever guy may say why can't you go for `/users/photos/{userId}/{photoId}`. Well I can't club many path parameters under the same URL.

How can I create a precise URL path with API Gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the section with the following heading in this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html#api-as-lambda-proxy-setup-iam-role-policies).

> Integration 3: Create a GET Method with Path Parameters to Call the Lambda Function